# How to denote a note that should only be played during first repeat without voltas?

Tags: notation, repeats

Look at this:
[image: excerpt with repeat barline and a note at the end marked]

I want to skip the note indicated with a red arrow on second repeat. I know about this solution:
[image: excerpt with repeat barline and volta bracket]

But I think it looks way to messy, considering it is only just one single note.

The main problem is that using voltas affects the staffs for other instruments too. So I want a solution that only affects the current staff.

How would you notate it?

Comment: I would replace the full rest under the seconda volta bracket by two halves: this aligns better with the bracket one and fits the rhythmic structure of 3/2.

Comment: @guidot I like the creativity of this, but that would only confuse the people who will be reading it. :)

Comment: Related: [Small changes between 1st and 2nd endings](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/97960/small-changes-between-1st-and-2nd-endings)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your lower solution isn’t messy at all, and is precisely the kind of thing 1st and 2nd time bars are used for. However, if you really don’t want to use them, simply bracket the notehead of the note you only want played the first time, and write in text above it “1st time only”.

Comment: I think the lower one looks very messy. I often use that construct for longer phrases, but for just one note I really want another solution.

Comment: But the main issue is that these voltas will also be in the staffs for other instruments.

Comment: If there was a volta in one staff and no voltas in the others--or vice versa--I'd get confused and think your sheet music is messy. Keep volta use consistent between all staves.

Comment: @Klutt that doesn’t matter. Performers are used to reading 1st and 2nd time bars that have no different notes in their own part. They will realise that this is because of changes in another part. This is very common in songs where the vocal part changes but instrumental parts are unchanged.

Comment: Textual hints lack the charm of internationality , and the text would become long if one wants to point out, that the note should be replaced by rest.

Comment: @guidot  So, fine:    Instead of "First Time Only",  write "Prima Volta".  For that matter, you could put a rest under the note and label it "Secunda Volta"

Comment: @klutt to add to what Bob B. commented: putting 1st and 2nd endings in all desks has the advantage of simplifying alterations or arrangements in the future.  You might want to add the pickup note for some other players, e.g.

Comment: @BobBroadley With all respect, you don't know the people who will read the music.

Comment: Nope, but I have composed and arranged music for hundreds of musicians. I’m just offering my advice. You certainly don’t have to accept it.

Comment: @BobBroadley I appreciate it. I upvoted your answer, but I have not accepted it yet in hope of a better solution coming up.