# Notation: How to notate a note at the start of the first bar that is only played during the first repeat?

Tags: notation, repeats

I have read [this answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/72887/how-to-denote-a-note-that-should-only-be-played-during-first-repeat-without-volt), which relates to a different problem.

I want to know how to include a note to be played at the start of my first bar (ie: *within* the bar, not prior to it), but only during the first repeat, not the initial play-through.

The first play-through commences with an eighth rest. On the first repeat I want to put an octave chord in place of that rest. Is there some kind of bracket notation that is used in such a circumstance?

Any advice which includes how to do this in Noteflight would be even more greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The classic solution would be to begin the repeat with the second measure and, if necessary, use first- and second-ending markings at the end of the repeated section, where the first ending contains the measure in question including the desired octave chord.

Another possibility is just to write "second time only" or "omit first time" over the octave chord, perhaps placing parentheses or square brackets around it.

I'd probably go with the first option because there's less room for ambiguity.

An example may be found in the fourth movement of Beethoven's fifth symphony.  Some recordings omit the repeats, but here's one that doesn't:

I'm afraid this question is my first exposure to Noteflight, so unfortunately I can't give you any specific help with that, but multiple endings at the end of repeated sections are such a standard feature of notation that it ought to support them.  If you're having trouble finding the feature, look for the Italian term *volta,* meaning "time" (as in "instance of repetition").

Comment: I just tried it with Noteflight, and it works during playback. I used your first recommendation. Thanks very much for the quick and accurate response.